# TypeError: setEmail is not a function. (In 'setEmail(input)', 'setEmail' is undefined) (unable to use hooks with context api)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-context

**App.js**

```
  const[getScreen, showScreen] = useState(false);
  const[getEmail, setEmail] = useState("");


<LoginScreen/>
<LoginContexts.Provider value={{getEmail,setEmail,getScreen,showScreen}}>
{showScreen?<Screen2/>:<LoginScreen/> }
</LoginContexts.Provider>
```

**Login Screen**

```
   import 
{ StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button
 } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';

import { LoginContexts } from '../Contexts/LoginContexts'

function LoginScreen (){
const {getEmail,setEmail,getScreen,showScreen} = useContext(LoginContexts);



return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>


        <View style={styles.textInput}>
            <TextInput  placeholder='Please enter your email'
            defaultValue={getEmail}
            onChange={(input) =>{setEmail(input)}}/>
        </View>
          **^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^Problem lies here^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^**
        <View style={styles.space}/>

        


        <View style={styles.space}/>

        <View>
            <Button style={styles.loginBTN} title="Login"
            onPress={() => {showScreen(true)}} />
        </View>
        </View>


    );
```

}

**Context API **

```
import { createContext} from "react";

export const  LoginContexts = createContext({});
```

**Screen 2**

```
const {getEmail} = useContext(LoginContexts);
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
   <LoginContexts.Consumer>
    {(fname)=> {
      <Text>{fname}</Text>;
    }}
    </LoginContexts.Consumer>
```

**When I am entering a text then program is giving me an error that setEmail is not a function.
I have taken out setEmail from useContext. My aim is to display text taken from user to another screen on button click**

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue. I am stuck on this problem from last two days. help me please

Comment: You're probably consuming the value outside the provider

Comment: I am importing the setEmail from  useContext then I am updating the state(setEmail) within return(); I am unable to use that state. what might be the problem ?

Comment: Why does `App.js` have two `LoginScreen`s? the one that is outside the provider will not be able to consume the context

Comment: do you mean this ->  ""<LoginScreen/>"" outside of the block of provider ?

Comment: @reddy is true. <LoginScreen/> should be within the provider else how will that access the contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of Context API is to avoid prop drilling and pass data to descending components in the vDOM.

If you want to pass asynchronous callbacks to change the data in your HOC, you’re effectively updating the state of your app, which is asking for quite a lot.

The resolution is to combine your Context with a reducer via useReducer hook.

Potential work around for current implementation is to remove the ternary from HOC:

replace `{showScreen?<Screen2/>:<LoginScreen/> }` with `{ children }` because when your showScreen's state is true you lose the reference to your callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

Pass it as array

```
<LoginContexts.Provider value={[getEmail,setEmail,getScreen,showScreen]}>
```

You need to change the order

```
const {getEmail,setEmail,getScreen,showScreen} = useContext(LoginContexts);
```

Comment: order doesn't matter when destructuring an object

Comment: I am getting the same error after replacing this line. what other error it might be to solve my problem. Please help me...

Comment: @RameshReddy can you explain how the order does not matter?

Comment: @SNSharma Read about object destructuring. OP's problem is not related to this.